# Execute script after change in particle count?

Tags: python, scripting, particles

I have the active object's particle count property laying out as it's own toolbar panel.

I'd like to have a script execute every time the user changes the particle count. Is it possible? I've heard of handlers, but can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the script I want to execute every time the particle count changes.

```
if bpy.context.scene.frame_current == 1:
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(0)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
```

Maybe add a custom property? Use modal operators?

Comment: try creating your own var with a setter and getter , when the user change this var you execute your code and change the particle count

Comment: Can you please provide an example. I can tweak it up after. Much thanks.